# When I run rails c on my terminal I get the pry error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I am new on rails and I am working on a practice project. I was trying to get the rails console started. However, when I run `rails c` I get the following:

```sh
"Running via Spring preloader in process 4495
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
[1] pry(main)> "
```

I would really like to understand what is happening and a solution would be more that appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ['pry' debugger](https://github.com/pry/pry) enabled (e.g. `pry-byebug` in your `Gemfile`) you'll get the `[1] pry(main)>` prompt. It isn't an error. You can set breakpoints and so on as documented. If you don't want it, remove the gem.

The `Cannot read termcap database; using dumb terminal settings.` is separate-ish. It means the app wants to use features of your terminal emulator, and it can't, because it can't see a file that tells it about that.

This will be something to do with your OS config (Windows, OSX, Ubuntu, etc).